# How to check if we have valid IBM MQ License

Tags: ibm-mq

Could any one let me know how can we check if we have `valid licenses for IBM MQ`.

Need to check it in LINUX, AIX and SunOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IBM Technote "[Upgrade the MQ trial version to a production version](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21254078)" states the following:

> Verify that the new license was applied by checking that the correct
>   license file (amqpcert.lic) is in the /opt/mqm/lib.
>
> The license is named amqXcert.lic, where X is the license type.
>
> - amqtcert.lic - is a trial license
> - amqbcert.lic - is a beta license
> - amqpcert.lic - is a full production license

---

The IBM MQ v7.1 Knowledge center page "[Converting a trial license on UNIX, Linux, and Windows](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/zi00111_.htm_)" states the following:

> Obtain the full license from the fully licensed installation media.

---

Based on the above statements if you have the file `amqpcert.lic` in the lib directory of the IBM MQ installation it only indicates your software was installed from fully licensed installation media or was upgraded from a trial or beta license to a full production license using fully licensed installation media.

The presence of this file however does **not** indicate you have a valid license.  A valid license would be based on what you have purchased.  If you purchased a license for one server and then used that installation media to install IBM MQ on 100 servers, the license file would be present on all the servers but you would only have a valid license for one server.

The following discussion on the MQSERIES Listserv has some good information on distributed licensing "[Re: License cost MQ - any overview?](https://listserv.meduniwien.ac.at/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1707&L=mqser-l&F=&S=&P=1249)".

Comment: Thank you for the inputs

Answer (score 0):

the approach in an IBM software license audit would be to run two commands against your server:

- dspmqver shows the version deployed and if a Queue Manager is running
- dspmq would show the actual queue and would be used to verify if you
  have an MQ server installed or just a free MQ client

Gabriel